Failing Okta OAuth2 django-okta-auth
i use django-okta-auth==0.8.0
my settings
WAGTAILADMIN_BASE_URL = env.str("FRONTEND_URL", default="http://localhost:8000")
# OKTA
OKTA_AUTH = {
    "ORG_URL": env.str("ORG_URL", default=""),
    "ISSUER": env.str("ORG_URL", default=""),
    "CLIENT_ID": env.str("CLIENT_ID", default=""),
    "CLIENT_SECRET": env.str("CLIENT_SECRET", default=""),
    "SCOPES": "openid profile email offline_access",  # this is the default and can be omitted
    "REDIRECT_URI": f"http://{FRONTEND_URL}/api/accounts/oauth2/callback",
    "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL": WAGTAIL_ADMIN_URL,  # default
    "CACHE_PREFIX": "okta",  # default
    "CACHE_ALIAS": "default",  # default
    "PUBLIC_NAMED_URLS": (),  # default
    "PUBLIC_URLS": (),  # default
    "USE_USERNAME": False,  # default
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "okta_oauth2.middleware.OktaMiddleware",
]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "okta_oauth2.backend.OktaBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]

after I enter the code on the okta page it redirects correctly to the GET page '/api/accounts/oauth2/callback' but the exception occurs MissingAuthTokens("Tokens missing from the session")
my SESSION_COOKIE_NAME=sessionid
and after exception ho redirect to the page '/api/accounts/login/'
What needs to be specified in the okta settings or in the settings of my application for authorization to work?
I tried changing the SESSION_COOKIE_NAME to those that come from okta, but none of them match and I can’t get the token
